# Is there nudity in any of the Mobile Suit Gundam series?

Tags: mobile-suit-gundam

I heard somewhere that there is some nudity in some of the Mobile Suit Gundam series, is this true?  And if so, which ones have it and how sexual is it?

I want to watch the shows with my little brother and I just want to make sure there's nothing like that in it before we start it.

Comment: Are you asking about just the original 1979 series that the accepted answer addresses or do you also want to know about the other ones?

Comment: mobile suit victory gundam: EP 29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the portion you're concerned with
IMDB states the following-

> Some characters (including children) do appear fully naked in bath scenes. Breasts are visible on female characters, and penises are visible on two child characters in one bath scene. There is a scene where one male child character rubs the chest of a female child character, though this is more comedic than sensual.
>
> There is implied to be a romantic interest between many characters on the show, but nothing sexual is even shown (or for that matter, hardly even implied.)

List of Bathing Scenes-

http://animebathscenewiki.com/index.php?title=Mobile_Suit_Gundam

For additional info you may refer to this link-

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0159172/parentalguide?ref_=m_ttpg

Comment: I saw this, but upon skimming the episode that's supposed to have the bath scene (ep. 22) I didn't find anything, hence why I made this post.

Comment: @justadude I just checked there isn't any such scene in episode 22 there's one in episode 21 of the first season. I'm updating the answer with a link which has a list of episodes with bathing scenes

Comment: @justadude in episode 21 there's a line which says 'but Kika's flat' supposedly according to this subreddit https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/42nore/spoilersuc_rewatch_mobile_suit_gundam_episode_22/ However be warned for spoilers on this subreddit

Comment: Yup, it seems ep. 21 does indeed have that scene.  That's really surprising considering it seems to be completely out of the blue, lol.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: EP 15 (Cucuruz Doan's Island) was cut from the international version of the show for undisclosed reasons at the request of the original creator. So in the original 43 episode run, the bath scene occurs in EP 22, in the dubs and rereleases it occurs in EP 21